# bibliography entries containing only one field

Tags: bibliographies

Is there a simple way to print only a single field in each bibliographic entry?  For a compact bibliography, I would like to print only the `note` field for each citation.  I am using the package `cite`, the bibliography style `unsrt`, and `bibtex(1)` to generate the `.bbl` file, but could switch to another citation package and back-end if it would facilitate a solution.

As an example, output would resemble the following

```
Lorem ipsum [1] dolor...

References
[1] Text from the 'note' field of this .bib entry.
```

Comment: Note that while the citation management package that's in use -- here, the `cite` package -- influences how citation call-outs are displayed, it has no effect on how the bibliographic entries are formatted and displayed.

Comment: My hunch is that you'll have to create an entirely new bibliography style (bst) that's programmed to display just the `note` field of each entry. I'm not aware of any pre-existing file that does this already.

Comment: @Mico: Thanks for pointing out that the citation package does not influence the bibliographic formatting.  Creating an entirely new bibliographic style would be challenging.  It sounds as though the objective may not be realizable by simply redefining a bibliography command.